# GATE CSE 2018, Which of the following languages are context-free?

Tags: context-free

> A] {a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>p</sup>d<sup>q</sup> | m+p = n+q,
> where m, n, p, q >=0}
>
> B] {a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>p</sup>d<sup>q</sup> | m = n and p
> = q, where m, n, p, q >=0}
>
> C] {a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>p</sup>d<sup>q</sup> | m = n = p
> and p not= q, where m, n, p, q >=0}
>
> D] {a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>p</sup>d<sup>q</sup> | mn = p+q,
> where m, n, p, q >=0}

**Instead of Formal proofs if any answer can provide telltale signs of a language being CFL or not will be more appreciated, because this question is taken from a competitive exam**. Formal proofs are welcome too.

Here is my approach

A] I don't have any idea for constructing PDA for this language, probably not a CFL. Also by pumping lemma splitting the word in 'uvwxy' for any 'vwx' (belonging to 'a<sup>k</sup>b<sup>k</sup>' and such combinations), the equality won't hold. Thus not a CFL.

B] Is a CFL we can push a's and pop on b's, same for c's and d's.

C] Not a CFL, as we need two stacks, one for keeping count of |a|==|b| and second for |b|==|c|.

D] Not a CFL, cause we can't construct a PDA, such a PDA will require capability to move back and forth on input string (for keeping track of m*n), which is not possible.

Comment: A) It's CFL. Rewrite it as $a^\ell (a^m b^m) (b^n c^n) (c^k d^k) d^\ell$. B) Yes. C), D) Yes, but your reasoning is not formal. Just use pumping lemma

Comment: rewriting A solves the problem and makes it easy too. @Dmitry, is there any quick way for D other than Pumping Lemma?

Comment: Actually, I simply don't know other tools for proving not-CFL aside from pumping lemma. That said, why not use it? It's pretty simple in this case.